# How to use jQuery-mobile functions within regular jQuery wrapper?

Tags: javascript, jquery, mobile, jquery-mobile, cordova

We have a PhoneGap app, jQuery-based, that has some problems with touch events (`touchstart` has selective behavior depending on phone-model [e.g. Galaxy vs. HTC] and `div` contents.. long story..).

We want to use jQuery-mobile just for the touch events (only good working solution currently found), since the code-base is pretty large and we're not going to port it completely to jQuery mobile overnight.

How can I use just the jQuery mobile events handlers within the regular jQuery environment ? meaning, the code is:

```
(function($){
    ...
})(jQuery)
```

so within that function, how do I use jQuery mobile functions ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Although I have not tried this explicitly but jQuery Mobile follows [AMD pattern](http://jquerymobile.com/blog/2012/01/10/upcoming-releases-1-0-1-1-1-and-beyond/) (>1.0.1) so it should be possible to use certain parts of core library independently.

https://github.com/jquery/jquery-mobile/blob/master/js/jquery.mobile.events.touch.js